# Joomla Warning - JLIB_FILESYSTEM_ERROR_PATH_IS_NOT_A_FOLDER_FOLDER

Tags: php, joomla, warnings, joomla3.0

[image]I have the following error periodically show up in Joomla 3.0/3.1/3.2 articles (front-end):

```
warning

JLIB_FILESYSTEM_ERROR_PATH_IS_NOT_A_FOLDER_FOLDER
JLIB_FILESYSTEM_ERROR_PATH_IS_NOT_A_FOLDER_FILES
```

It first shows up right after install, and then disappears upon refreshing, but reappears at random times later. Does anyone know about this?

BTW, I know very little about MySQL and PHP other than setting up a database and coding a template, so if you could be descriptive, that would be awesome :)

EDIT: Maybe it's because I am installing a pre-configured package with Akeeba? But I'm pretty sure I have got this message  even when I installed the actual Joomla package.

Comment: You have specified 3 different version of Joomla, which are you using? You have also mentioned you get this error in the frontend when viewing articles, but then also mention it showing right after installing, so which is it?

Comment: It has happened to all 3 versions, which is why I listed all of them. I still have both 3.1 and 3.2 sites, and the error sometimes pops up for both of those versions. It happens right after install when I visit the front-end for the first time, so when I see the article for the first time, right after install. does that make sense?